# How to download files that are dynamically served

Tags: linux, wget

I've run into this a few times when a site serves a variable file i try to download

`wget http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/latest/tracajaxcommentsplugin?old_path=/&filename=tracajaxcommentsplugin&format=zip`

Expected file

`tracajaxcommentsplugin-r10913.zip` 
instead I get a file 
`tracajaxcommentsplugin\?old_path\=%2F` with content

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" ...
```

This problem is not specific to trac or this pecific file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it with a single quote:

`$ wget 'http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/latest/tracajaxcommentsplugin?old_path=/&filename=tracajaxcommentsplugin&format=zip' -O tracajaxcommentsplugin-r10913.zip`

Comment: On XP and the like, wrap the command in a double quote to get the same result.